# Scatter plot on melted data set

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the following data

```
dt <- data.frame(id1 = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10), id2=rep(1:10, 2), value = rnorm(20))
```

What I want is to do a scatter plot of `A` vs `B`. This is can be done, after rearranging the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
qplot(A, B, data=dt %>% spread(id1,value))
```

Is it possible to do without the data rearrangement? The thing is that in my case the values in the column `id1` can be arbitrary, so I would have to do some additional housekeeping to achieve the same result, something like:

```
cd <- dt %>% spread(id1, value)
nm_cd <- colnames(cd)[-1]
colnames(cd)[-1] <- c("x", "y")
qplot(x, y, data=cd) + labs(x = nm_cd[1], y = nm_cd[2])
```

I am curious is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the base `plot` function, the approach is quite easy since labels are generated automatically:

```
plot(do.call(cbind, split(dt$value, dt$id1)))
```

[image]

Another approach with `qplot`:

```
dat <- split(dt$value, dt$id1)
qplot(dat[[1]], dat[[2]], xlab = names(dat)[1], ylab = names(dat)[2])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe something like that will work for you?

```
ggplot(dt, aes(value[id1 == levels(id1)[1]], value[id1 == levels(id1)[2]])) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = levels(dt$id1)[1], y = levels(dt$id1)[2])
```

[image]